# How to compute proportion of variable in one dataframe based on data in another dataframe

Tags: r

I have two dataframes:

```
df1 <- data.frame(popPerGroup = c(NA, 4153813, 4753258, 6716294, 7079839, 8218844, 8476699, 6453706, 3560646, 1623932, 227805),
                  ageGroup = c("NA","0-9","10-19","20-29","30-39","40-49","50-59","60-69","70-79","80-89","90-99"))

df2 <- data.frame(ageGroup = c("30", "40", "50", "60", "70", "80", "90"),
                  nCases = c(1,2,7,12, 21,25,7))
```

I want to compute the proportion of `df2$nCases` per `df2$ageGroup` out of the matching `df1$popPerGroup` values in `df1`. First I tackle the problem of the different `ageGroup` values with a regex operation using `sub`:

```
df1$ageGroupNew <- sub("^(\\d+)-\\d+$", "\\1", df1$ageGroup, perl = T)
```

This works fine. But the next operation using `match`(partly) fails as the proportions for the higher `ageGroup`s are given as `NA`:

```
df2$populProp <- df2$nCases[match(df2$ageGroup, df1$ageGroupNew)] / df1$popPerGroup[match(df2$ageGroup, df1$ageGroupNew)]
df2
  ageGroup nCases    populProp
1       30      1 2.966169e-06
2       40      2 3.041790e-06
3       50      7 8.257932e-07
4       60     12           NA
5       70     21           NA
6       80     25           NA
7       90      7           NA
```

How can the code be mended so that all proportions are correctly computed?

EDIT:

The solution is actually quite simple:

```
df2$populProp <- df2$nCases / df1$popPerGroup[match(df2$ageGroup, df1$ageGroupNew)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not seem to match the right numerator with the right denominator (your `match` calls give you indices in `df1` but you subset in `df2`):

```r
df1 <- transform(df1, ageGroupNew = sub("^(\\d+)-\\d+$", "\\1", ageGroup, 
                                        perl = T))
df2[match(df2$ageGroup, df1$ageGroupNew), ]
#R>      ageGroup nCases
#R> 5          70     21
#R> 6          80     25
#R> 7          90      7
#R> NA       <NA>     NA
#R> NA.1     <NA>     NA
#R> NA.2     <NA>     NA
#R> NA.3     <NA>     NA
df1[match(df2$ageGroup, df1$ageGroupNew), ]
#R>    popPerGroup ageGroup ageGroupNew
#R> 5      7079839    30-39          30
#R> 6      8218844    40-49          40
#R> 7      8476699    50-59          50
#R> 8      6453706    60-69          60
#R> 9      3560646    70-79          70
#R> 10     1623932    80-89          80
#R> 11      227805    90-99          90
```

Maybe this will do?

```r
# create ageGroupNew
df1 <- transform(df1, ageGroupNew = sub("^(\\d+)-\\d+$", "\\1", ageGroup, 
                                        perl = T))

# merge into one table and do the calculation
df_merge <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = "ageGroupNew", by.y = "ageGroup")
df_merge <- transform(df_merge, populProp = nCases / popPerGroup)
df_merge[, c("ageGroup", "nCases", "populProp")]
#R>   ageGroup nCases    populProp
#R> 1    30-39      1 1.412461e-07
#R> 2    40-49      2 2.433432e-07
#R> 3    50-59      7 8.257932e-07
#R> 4    60-69     12 1.859397e-06
#R> 5    70-79     21 5.897806e-06
#R> 6    80-89     25 1.539473e-05
#R> 7    90-99      7 3.072803e-05
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It's actually quite simple: `df2$populProp <- df2$nCases / df1$popPerGroup[match(df2$ageGroup, df1$ageGroupNew)]`works--just as yours!